# <select> <option> element hover glitches if <select> has hover style applied

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select

When selecting something from `<select>` while there is a diferent style on hover it makes reset hovered `<option>` to initial state. How can I overcome this, because if there is a `transition` property present it makes it even worse?

**EDIT:**

- <strike>FF23,IE10,O12.5 doesn't seem to have this problem</strike>
- Safari and Google Chrome apparently have this problem.

To see what I'm talking about follow these steps:

1. Select last option
2. Click on select box
3. Slowly move mouse down over the options, now you can see how options are glitching

EXAMPLE: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/ur9Vg/)

CSS:

```
select {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
}
select:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="mankind">Man kind</option>
    <option value="humankind">Human kind</option>
    <option value="animalkind">Animal kind</option>
</select>
```

---

**This seems to be Chrome related bug**

- Issue [287193](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287193)
- Related Issue [289326](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=289326)

Answer (score 1):

I hope, that I don`t misunderstand your question.

Try this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur9Vg/12/)

```
select {
    outline: 0; 
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
}
select:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I put in `select` the `outline:0`

Comment: While this reduces the deffect it doesn't remove it. :(. +1 for reducing effect caused.

Comment: @skmasq - try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur9Vg/18/) out - I change `transition: all 0.35s ease-out;` to `transition: ease-out 0.3s border;` - I tested on last Chrome, FF and Safari.. and I see nothing strange...

Comment: You can see while slowly moving mouse down it glitches between options.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do anything about it..looks like issue surrounding control rendering when easing.

If you are insistent on the behavior, you can prob. cheat it--can you package SELECT inside div and ease the div?

```
<div class="whizbangselect">
  <select>
    <option value="mankind">Man kind</option>
    <option value="humankind">Human kind</option>
    <option value="animalkind">Animal kind</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

style:

```
select {
    border: none;
}
div.whizbangselect {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;

    -moz-transition: border 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: border 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: border 1s ease-out;
    transition: border 1s ease-out;
}
div.whizbangselect:hover { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Note: you'll have to play with padding

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/ezc4Z/ - you can see here, on mouse out browser still resets the value. On the positive side it doesn't glitch at all while in box. Nice hack thou.

Comment: Looks for webkit does not treat mouseover over the dropdown's panel as a hover, whereas FF does--once you mouseout of the panel, you dont get hover until you mouseover the actual dropdown control.  May just be what it is.

Comment: What's interesting it looks like this hasn't been an issue, while I'm thinking this is very obvious.